# .htaccess RewriteRule for search query page

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want to write a rewrite rule for my search page, which must satisfy the following:

**Display URL:**

```
/search?q=SEARCH-QUERY
```

**Actual URL:**

```
/search.php?q=SEARCH-QUERY
```

I tried the following but it didn't work:

```
RewriteRule ^search?q=(.*)$ search.php?q=%1 [QSA]
```

I've checked many related questions but couldn't find an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your shown samples, could you please try following. Please clear your browser cache before testing your URLs. You were checking query string in rewriterule which will not work because query string could be matched either in a condition to variable `QUERY_STRING` OR in variable `THE_REQUEST` so I am using later option here.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/(search)\?q=SEARCH-QUERY\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1.php [L,QSA]
```

Comment: @Envayo, oh ok in that case kindly use `RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/(search)\?q=[^\s]*\s [NC]` once and let me know, once you confirm then I will edit my answer, cheers. And `.*` is greedy regex it will match everything we need to match like this shown way here.

Comment: Sorry, I was going to post an edited comment, but seems you posted quicker. Yes, that worked. Please let me test a bit more, before accepting your answer. Thank you very much! :)

Comment: What about search results page with pagination? How should I modify the rewriterule to redirect `/search?q=SEARCH-QUERY` to `/search.php?q=SEARCH-QUERY` and `/search?q=SEARCH-QUERY&page=N` to `/search.php?q=SEARCH-QUERY&page=N`? N is an integer.

Comment: @Envayo, Hello, greetings!! would like to request you to open a new question(to avoid any confusion to future users) and we could discuss it there, please do let me know link of new question once you open it, cheers.

Comment: Hello, asked it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66793421/htaccess-rewriterule-for-search-page-with-pagination