# .htaccess RewriteRule for search page with pagination

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want to write a rewrite rule for my search results page with pagination, which must satisfy the following:

**Display URL 1:**

```
/search?q=SEARCH-QUERY
```

**Actual URL 1:**

```
/search.php?q=SEARCH-QUERY
```

and

**Display URL 2:**

```
/search?q=QUERY&p=N
```

**Actual URL 2:**

```
/search.php?q=QUERY&p=N
```

where **QUERY** is a variable string (user input) and **N** is an integer (page number).

I have the following which satisfies condition 1 above, but I couldn't manage to modify it to also satisfy condition 2.

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/(search)\?q=[^\s]*\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1.php [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your shown samples, could you please try following once.
Please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/(search)\?(?:q=[^\s]*)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1.php [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/(search)\?(?:q=[^\s]*)&(?:p=[0-9]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1.php [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thank you, but the above code did not work. While doing some tests, I figured using two conditions and rules worked. I will post it as answer below, in case anyone else may need.

Comment: @Envayo, oh ok, I have edited the rules now, taken inspiration from your tried ones and enhanced them and modified flag, kindly do check them once and let me know if this helps you?

Comment: Yea, it worked. One last question, what is the role of `?:` in the parenthesis? Regex cheatsheet says `(?:abc)` is non-capturing group.

Comment: @Envayo, yeah that's correct, its a non capturing group since we want to check it in a group(while doing matches checks) but we don't want it to be considered as a group(it will NOT be numbered like it does in `(...)`), that's why non capturing groups are handy, cheers and happy learning :)